# How to get the elements bound to a model in Knockoutjs 

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, dom-node

I want to add a product, find the node an let it flash

```
products = observableArray([]);

new_product = new Product();
products.push(new_product);
$("tr", new_product.elements).flash();
```

I tried using afterAdd but it flashed each time I added something.
I need to flash only with one of my adding function. The other functions which add should not flash the element.

NOTE: flash is a custom JQuery function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since an observable can be bound to multiple elements, your best bet is to really come at it from the element in the form of a custom binding.

At its simplest, you could use a binding like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.flash = {
    init: function(element) {
        $(element).flash();
    }
};
```

Use it on your element like: `<li data-bind="flash: true"></li>`.  In this case what you pass to the binding does not matter.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Exmvh/

You can certainly pass options to your binding like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.flash = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var duration = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).hide().flash(duration);
    }
};
```

And use it like: `<li data-bind="flash: 500"></li>` or use an observable that you can use to control the duration: `<li data-bind="flash: selectedDuration"></li>`

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Exmvh/1/

Comment: Thanks but I think this the same as using "afterAdd: flash"

Comment: How can I get the multiple elements of an observable?

Comment: This advantage to using a binding is that you can be explicit on which elements have the binding and have a better change to pass options and respond to observables.  Can you clarify a bit what you mean by multiple elements of an observable?

Comment: Also, one way to prevent your initial elements from "flashing" is to either set a 0 duration until after start up, or read a flag to indicate that it is okay to animate now.

Comment: Here is another sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Exmvh/2/.  Kind of gets at your need to sometimes flash and sometimes not.

Comment: RP Niemeyer, how can you get code to run 'after start up'.  I'm looking for a way to set duration or a flag after applyBindings, but can't find a good way to do this.

Comment: Generally your options would be something like have `duration` be an observable and pass it to the binding or what I like to do a lot is add "global" options to the custom binding.  So, you would set `ko.bindingHandlers.flash.duration = yourvalue` and then read it in the custom binding from that location.  Not sure if that matches your scenario.  Maybe throw a fiddle together.  I would be happy to help.

Comment: ok, so what seems to work for now is that i just set ko.bindingsApplied = false before I call ko.applyBindings, and then set it to true afterwards.  Then I can see if I should flash or not by reading ko.bindingsApplied.