# Get element an observable is bound to with Knockout?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

This isn't an ideal situation, but due to another knockout binding I am using I am in a situation where I am needing to get the element an observable is bound to, if it is indeed bound to anything.

So is there a way to do this?

== Update ==

I didn't want to add any extra context incase it confuses the question, but as it may get an answer more in line with expectations here is the scenario.

I am using the knockout validation binding, which exposes all the errors using the `ko.validation.group(model)` method. However the problem is that *only* gives you the textual errors, it does not give you any context as to what part of the model gave you those errors. So I have made a small change to the source to now pass back the observable tied to each error, as this may be useful for a few scenarios, but from here I need to be able to tie this to an element so I can display some in-line validation of some kind.

Knockout Validation provides a very basic in-line validation where it creates a span after your element and you can give it a class, but this is too basic for my needs as currently we are using Qtip and other notification systems to display validation errors, and because of this I need to be able to have a Dom element and an error. So far I have an observable and an error, but I need to tie that observable object (which could be any ko.observable() property from the model) to its given DOM element, if it does have an element binding.

As all I have is an object and I am using validation driven from the model not the UI, the problem is not really going to be solved via a custom binding. Ideally I need to be able to crack open the marry up the observable object (an unknown `ko.observable()`) to an element.

Not to go too project specific, but my current project abstracts validation where events are fired off (i.e `EventSystem.SendEvent(ValidationEvents.ValidationFailed, <element>, <error>)`) then a validation system listens for these events and ties the error to the element, be it a tooltip, a growl style notification, an alert box etc. So I am trying to find the best way to keep this abstraction when driving the validation from the models observables not the ui's DOM elements (i.e jquery-ui)

== Edit 2 ==

I was a bit thrown by the way Knockout Validation knows the elements for observables to put in its own validation elements, however they just piggy back off the existing value binding, so I am just going to change that to add the elements for any validation elements based on their `isValidatable()` method, at least that way for each error I can tie it to an observable, and for any observables with element bindings I can tie them to the elements, and if there are none then it is fine they would just be form wide validation errors. I will give this a try as this should be something like (not tested yet):

```
if(utils.isValidatable(valueAccessor())) {
    valueAccessor().extend({hasElementalBinding: true, elementalBinding: element});
}
else { 
    valueAccessor().extend({hasElementalBinding: false});
}
```

At around line 250 in the `registerValueBindingHandler`, I will leave this question open for a while longer incase someone else has a better solution.

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911544/how-to-get-the-elements-bound-to-a-model-in-knockoutjs

Comment: Not really, its just about a custom binding, I am in a scenario where I have access to an observable, but need to add a new DOM element and know what element to tie it to.

Comment: I really think you should just write your own custom validation binding , because then you will get an element and can do with it what you will.

Comment: After rethinking this approach based on your previous question it may be a case of writing something like a BoundTo binding or something which injects the element into the observable for later lookups. It sounds nasty though, but I cannot think of a way around it really if the element is only available within the scope of the bindings... thanks for the info so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't be very fast, so I would definitely cache the results, but something using jQuery's attribute selectors:

```
$('[data-bind*="Property"]')
```

`*=` is the attribute contains selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Obviously this won't catch anything that subscribed manually using the `.subscribe` method, but I'm not sure how you would extract element's from the functions anyway.

**Disclaimer:** while this solution will probably work, this sounds like a horrible idea to me, I would instead write a custom binding (as mentioned in the comments) or find some other solution.

Comment: How can you get the property in this example? This is the crux of my problem, I have the observable object so observable() gives me the value of it, but it could be 1 of 100 observables, so I need to know ideally if there is some uniquely identifiable part of the observable object that I can use to get the dom element, or even if it is exposed somehow directly from the observable object, as it must use it under the covers. I didn't want to pollute the question with more context than was needed but it may be better explaining this.

Comment: Ah, then the answer is no with the current bindings.  But you could easily write a custom binding to use instead of value or something that exposes its list of dom elements.

Comment: You can see in the source for the `value` binding, that it doesn't actually expose the DOM element publicly: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings.js

Comment: I may be wrong but you are talking about ``value`` which is a binding, I am talking about an observable ``ko.observable()``, one is a binding function to be used within html, the other is a variable/function to be used within javascript. I have edited the post to hopefully give people more clarity of the problem.

Comment: Yeah I get the difference, the problem is that only bindings are bound to elements, observables just have subscribers which are functions.  You can only get an element from a binding.

Comment: Ah yes I see the angle you are coming from, because the value binding is what ties an element to an observable you are saying that really the observable has no knowledge of the relationship with the element. Hmm will have to have a think over this now you have pointed it out.

Answer (score 18):

I have done something similar to what you mentioned above. My data-bind tag includes a custom binding:

```
data-bind="... myvalidationbinding: myobservable"
```

Then in my binding handler I extend the observable

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myvalidationbinding = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) { 
    valueAccessor().extend({element: element });
  }
};
```

And finally my extension is

```
ko.extenders.element = function (target, element) {
  target.DOMElement = element;
}
```

Now I can subscribe to isValid() given by knockout.validation and if not valid, go get the element the observable is bound to and then manipulate it with jQuery.

Comment: What if the observable is bound to more than one element?

Comment: extending the Jon Keto answer for add multiple elements binded at the same observable: 'target.DOMElements = target.DOMElements || [];
        target.DOMElements.push(element);'

Comment: +1 What a wonderful extender!! I don't know if it's a good practice to have access to the DOM element from the viewModel but in my case, right now, the design is much much simpler.

Comment: @vfportero what happens if the bound element is destroyed ? how to clear the ref ?