# Get bindings from observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

How can I get `data-bind` string or DOM nodes which an observable is bound to? I'm using knockout.validation.js on my web page and one of my default validations (`required`) is getting fired. I'd like to find out which one is it being inside for example `validateSync` @ knockout.validation.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I came with something like this:

```
    function getPath(source, propertyName /*, value, result, noDescend */) {
        var result = arguments[3] || {};
        var valueToFind = arguments[2];
        var noDescend = arguments[4];

        function merge(dst, name, src) {
            var result = {};
            result[name] = src;

            return $.extend(true, dst, result);
        }

        for (var p in source) {
            var value = source[p];
            if (p == propertyName) {
                if (!valueToFind || source[p]==valueToFind) {
                    result[p] = source[p];
                }
            }
            else {
                if (!noDescend && (typeof value == 'object' || typeof value == 'function')) {
                    if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                        var r = getPath(value, propertyName, valueToFind, result[p], true);

                        if (Object.keys(r).length > 0) merge(result, p, r);
                    }

                    var r = getPath(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value), propertyName, valueToFind, result[p]);
                    if (Object.keys(r).length > 0) merge(result, p, r);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This function will give you an object which only contains properties (despite its nesting level) on name `propertyName`. The object being searched is `source`. The solution is based on the fact, that an observable has field `_id` when it gets bound. Here's a use case where this function is helpful.

1. In a non-trivial form with fields bound to a non-trivial view model one of the fields breaks validation.
2. After placing a breakpoint inside true-path of `if` statement in function `validateSync` in `knockout.validation.js`, check obeservable's ID by calling:

   ```
   observable._id
   ```
3. Call the following command to get all the fields which breaks validation:

   ```
   getPath(ko.dataFor($('<form-selector>')[0]),'_id',<id-of-observable>)
   ```

If anyone finds a better solution, please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get the actual value of the data-bind attribute

```
<span data-bind="value: test"> </span>


$(function() {
   // this will get you "value: test"
   alert($('span').attr('data-bind'));
});
```

Also if you want to get the actual observable that you bound to you can use ko.dataFor function.

ko.dataFor(element) - returns the data that was available for binding against the element
ko.contextFor(element) - returns the entire binding context that was available to the DOM element.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I already have the whole observable (see `validateSync` in `knockout.validation.js`). I want to know to what element it is bound or what is its context or anything else to help me identify property on which validator breaks.

Comment: So you are  trying to get actual HTML elements that are bound to your observable, right?

Comment: Well... more or less yes. I'm trying to get anything that will help me spot failing field in a large view model.

Comment: I don't know what the name of the observable is - keep that in mind, please.

Comment: What is your end goal? Why do you need the observable name itself for? You can use this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465200/get-element-an-observable-is-bound-to-with-knockout with jquery attribute selector, something along the lines like I posted in the answer. But it does sound like a bad idea honestly.