# KnockOut js get all observable views by viewmodel

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

Another Knockout.JS question driving me crazy. I'm having a single view-model. Multiple Views are dynamically created and bindings are applied dynamically. Now, I'm trying to remove bindings dynamically on user actions. But, i need to know if there are any observers are interested in specific variable before removing from view-model. See one of my use case below:

```
<div id="e1" data-bind="graph: a0001, var1: a0002, var2: a0003, var3: a0004"&nbsp;</div>
<div id="e2" data-bind="button:a0002"&nbsp;</div>
```

Later on user action, created a new div

```
<div id="e3" data-bind="graph:a0001"&nbsp;</div>
```

and all **a0001,a0002,a0003** are bind to same view-model **vm**. All data flowing to different views and everything is fine.

Now, On user action, i want to

- **delete #e2**.
- get all variables bind to **#e2 (a0002)**
- check if any other element bind to that variable.

  - if other elements bind to variable, ignore and continue.
  - if no other element bind to variable, remove it from **vm**

So, to achieve above, i need to get all views (DOM elements) bind to variable by variable.

Would appreciate if anyone can give me some thoughts to achieve same without performance impact.

Comment: If jQuery is an option, then this post might be of some use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465200/get-element-an-observable-is-bound-to-with-knockout

Comment: It seems like a backwards way of working: your viewModel should drive your template, not the other way around.

Comment: @alex, Thanks for your comment. jQuery is an option and the thread is saying same thing what i've as backup options which is impacting my app performance. So, Yes as suggestion and no as answer bcz not giving expected performance.

Comment: @Retsam, Thanks for your comment. It may look working backward. But, I tried all possibilities to avoid this. But, my requirement is forcing to look into possibilities this way. By design, MVC/VM are not reversible?

Comment: All observbles have a property called "getSubscriptionsCount".  Each bound element will (at a minimum) increase this count by 1.

If (in your example) vm.a0002 is an observable and vm.a0002.getSubscriptionsCount() === 0 then there is nothing left bound from the UI.

Of course other computeds will increase this count as well, but it could be a useful indicator

Comment: @RobertSlaney, This is what i'm looking for now. Instead of searching over my Huge DOM structure, i can use a simple javascript number which is pre computed by ko, which would serve my purpose. But, still i'm keeping this question open, to see if anyone can tell me how to get reference DOM elements also (need in future). You can add this as answer also.  Thanks for your response though.