# Get bounded property from element with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a element bounded to a viewModel

```
<input id="myId" data-bind="text: myProperty"></input>
```

Later, in a script I need to set the property that is bound to the element. I have a script doing it like this;

```
<script>
    //mySelector can be any element in our current case it will be "#myId"
    //focusout is just the event that triggers the action, it could be others also
    $(mySelector).focusout(function (){
       var observable = ko.dataFor(this);
       var context = ko.contextFor(this);

       // I could do
       observable.myProperty('Some Value');
       //but it could be anything, I need to retrieve the property from mySelector
       //how can this be done?

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465200/get-element-an-observable-is-bound-to-with-knockout?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You're running in to problems because you're mixing a jQuery-approach with knockout. The general rules when working with knockout are:

- use two-way bindings rather than event listeners
- when really needed, use the `event` binding for event handling
- only touch the DOM via data-binds

If you absolutely wish to keep going in your chosen direction, you can reevaluate the data-bind attribute to find out the property bound to `text` (*not recommended*).

```js
ko.applyBindings({ myProperty: ko.observable("Initial text") });


const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
const bindingString = h1.getAttribute("data-bind");
const bindingObject = ko.expressionRewriting.parseObjectLiteral(bindingString);
const textBinding = bindingObject.find(({ key }) => key === "text");

if (textBinding) {
  const vm = ko.dataFor(h1);
  const obsProp = vm[textBinding.value];
  
  obsProp("Hello world")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h1 data-bind="text: myProperty"></h1>
```

However, I'd do something like this:

```js
const hasFocus = ko.observable(false);
const label = ko.pureComputed(
  () => hasFocus() ? "Hello world" : "Initial text"
);

ko.applyBindings({ hasFocus, label })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
  <input data-bind="hasFocus: hasFocus" placeholder="focus on me to see something happen!">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Among others, You can directly bind the `focusout` event in knockout:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.myProperty = ko.observable("my text");
  self.onfocus = function(data, event) {
    // do something on focus
    var currText = self.myProperty.peek();
  };
  self.onfocusout = function(data, event) {
    // do something on focusout (or blur)
    var currText = self.myProperty.peek();
    var newText = currText.split("").reverse().join("");
    self.myProperty(newText);
  };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="myId" data-bind="value: myProperty, event: {focus: onfocus, focusout: onfocusout }">
      <hr/>
      <pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data)"></pre>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```